# Fast way to calculate sum over the outer products of 2-d array, with the shape of (2, 5) in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy 2-d array, with the shape of (2, 5) (could be more dimensions (m,n))

```
A=array([[2.64859009e-02, 2.17771938e-02, 2.38019379e+00, 7.35715883e-01,6.89917290e-01],
      [6.89917290e-01, 5.67262659e-01, 6.20004150e+01, 1.91642758e+01,1.79712923e+01]]
```

I want to generate two 5 by 5 matrices, which is the outer product of each array within array A itself.

The first matrix should be the outer product of `[2.64859009e-02, 2.17771938e-02, 2.38019379e+00, 7.35715883e-01,6.89917290e-01]` with `[2.64859009e-02, 2.17771938e-02, 2.38019379e+00, 7.35715883e-01,6.89917290e-01]`, and the second matrix should be the outer product of `[6.89917290e-01, 5.67262659e-01, 6.20004150e+01, 1.91642758e+01,1.79712923e+01]` with `[6.89917290e-01, 5.67262659e-01, 6.20004150e+01, 1.91642758e+01,1.79712923e+01]`.

After that calculation, I want to sum over every element of the two 5 by 5 matrices, which finally outputs as one 5 by 5 matrix.

```
A[0] outer* A[0] + A[1] outer* A[1]
```

Is there a fast way to do it in numpy?

Comment: How is it two 5*5 matrices. outer Product of A[0] and A[1] will give you one 5*5 matrix. Unless, I've understood the question wrong.

Comment: Hi I just edited this question to make it more clear, it is the outer product of `A[0]` and `A[0]`, and `A[1]` and `A[1]`

Comment: Another way to describe `A` is as a 2d array, with shape (2,5).  Have you looked at `np.outer`?

Answer (score 2):

Let's make a simpler test array:

```
In [254]: A = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
In [255]: A
Out[255]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [256]: A.shape
Out[256]: (2, 5)
```

Given the way you describe the problem, `np.outer` should be easy to apply:

```
In [257]: np.outer(A[0],A[0])+np.outer(A[1],A[1])
Out[257]: 
array([[25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
       [30, 37, 44, 51, 58],
       [35, 44, 53, 62, 71],
       [40, 51, 62, 73, 84],
       [45, 58, 71, 84, 97]])
```

`np.outer`  only works with 1d arrays, not the whole 2d `A`.  But we can do the same sort of `outer` using `broadcasting`.  The result will be a (2,5,5) array, which we can then sum on the first axis:

```
In [260]: (A[:,:,None]*A[:,None,:]).sum(axis=0)
Out[260]: 
array([[25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
       [30, 37, 44, 51, 58],
       [35, 44, 53, 62, 71],
       [40, 51, 62, 73, 84],
       [45, 58, 71, 84, 97]])
```

`np.einsum` is also a convenient way of describing this sort of operation (if you are used to dealing with axis indices):

```
In [261]: np.einsum('ij,ik->jk',A,A)
Out[261]: 
array([[25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
       [30, 37, 44, 51, 58],
       [35, 44, 53, 62, 71],
       [40, 51, 62, 73, 84],
       [45, 58, 71, 84, 97]])
```

But that `einsum` sure looks like a `dot` product, a sum of products.  We just need to tranpose the first array:

```
np.einsum('ji,ik->jk', A.T,A)
```

or with `np.dot`:

```
In [262]: np.dot(A.T,A)
Out[262]: 
array([[25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
       [30, 37, 44, 51, 58],
       [35, 44, 53, 62, 71],
       [40, 51, 62, 73, 84],
       [45, 58, 71, 84, 97]])
```

Comment: Amazing! Learned from it:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.outer` method from  [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html).

`A=np.array([[2.64859009e-02, 2.17771938e-02, 2.38019379e+00, 7.35715883e-01,6.89917290e-01],[6.89917290e-01, 5.67262659e-01, 6.20004150e+01, 1.91642758e+01,1.79712923e+01]])
b = np.outer(A[0],A[0])
c = np.outer(A[1],A[1])`

Simple sum of `b+c` should be sufficient to do the last step.

Comment: What if I still want to save them to an array?

Comment: `b` and `c` are numpy arrays. If you want a single array. You can always stack them as required